# What happens if node server isnt connected when agenda job is scheduled to run

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, jobs, job-scheduling

Hi I was wondering what will happen to an agenda job that is scheduled to run every 24 hours if we turn off the server for two days? When we restart the server, will it be able to pick up where it left off? Or what?

Can't seem to find documentation on this so on server restart what I'm doing is removing the task and then recreating it...but not sure if this is efficient way.

https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda